# Splitting Code into Headers/Source files in PHP

Tags: php

In C++, each class has a `.h` file and a `.cpp` file, is that possible in PHP?

The reason i want this for, is that when i give my class file to another person to use it I dont want him to view my source code,

I just want him to use the class without viewing the source.

Comment: You perhaps need to obfuscate your code.. It will make code non-human-readable. It is impossible to allow someone to have your class without viewing it's source code.

Comment: Does "use" mean actual production or just an interface to write code against? In the latter case you could just provide API documentation or use an [`interface`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php)

Comment: uses means to create an object of the class and call its functions

Comment: And why is that person not allowed to see the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, PHP doesn't have an equivalent of header files. You may want something like http://www.ioncube.com or http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/.

Really ask yourself *why* you're doing this before going down this route though.